# "Bubble" validation message on non-form element

Tags: javascript, html, validation

I have some elements on a page and I want to make use of the nice bubble style messages such as described here [HTML5 form validation](http://stephenwalther.com/archive/2012/03/13/html5-form-validation.aspx). It seems that to use them it is required they are within a form element and they only can be used on validation once the form is attempted to be submitted.

Taking from the linked example, I want to know how to get the following to work as described (i.e for this example pop a bubble message if the user sets a time before now)

Fiddle for this: [My attempt without form](http://jsfiddle.net/QGpQj/1/)

```
<body>
    <label>
      Arrival Date:
      <input id="arrivalDate" type="date" onchange="dateChanged()" />
    </label>
    <input type="button" value="Test Reservation"></input>

  <script type="text/javascript">
  function dateChanged(e){
      var arrivalDate = document.getElementById("arrivalDate");
      var value = new Date(arrivalDate.value);
      if (value < new Date()) {
          arrivalDate.setCustomValidity("Arrival date must be after now!");
      } else {
          arrivalDate.setCustomValidity("");
      }
      arrivalDate.checkValidity();
  }
  </script>
</body>
```

Specifically in my case I have 2 KendoUI DateTimePickers being used to select the time range which is used to display information dynamically on the page. I'd like if I could use these bubble messages if the user tries to make the start time after the end time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to manually trigger the validation. Using `.checkValidity()` will only return true/false if the context of what your checking is valid or not, i.e. if you did `form.checkValidity()` it will check if all form elements are valid, or `input.checkValidity()` only check the validity of that single element.

The only way to trigger the validation is on submit. You can simulate this by having a submit button and calling the `click` function.

```
if (!arrivalDate.checkValidity())
{
    document.getElementById('submit_reservation').click();
}
```

**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/QGpQj/3/

Note: I've added `window.dateChanged = ....` because of your inline event listener. You really should be using `.addEventListener` or, ideally, jQuery for this to add backwards compatability support for those non-supported browsers.

Comment: So there's no way to use this popup balloon without a form?

Comment: @judgeja Unfortunately not. Is there any reason why you don't want to wrap it into a form?

Comment: My elements aren't showing up properly at all when wrapped in a form. I'm sure there's some simple fix but I can't find it. I'm using knockoutJS (which I'm new to) and the form elements are all just being displayed one under the other.

Comment: I abandoned trying to use those bubble message popups and am just using a simple little error message, since as you said it doesn't seem to be possible to use this as I would like.